# Overloading [] and + simultaneously

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have class which has array inside.

Suppose we have class A and array12 inside it.

All I need to do is `A[index]+value` so I suppose add to array12[index] that value.

```
int &operator[](int index)
{
    return array12[index];
}
```

But what I need write when I overload operator +?

How do I know element index when overloading +?

Comment: Could you provide an example and an expected result?

Comment: It seems like you're trying too hard. Either that or I've misunderstood what you're trying to do. The value of the expression `A[index] + value` is `array12[index] + value`. Or, if you want to use `+` to change the value of `array12[index]`, don't; use `+=`, which already works: `A[index] += value` does the same thing as `array12[index] += value`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't directly overload an operator to solve this as `operator+` takes only argument. This is not possible:

```
void operator+(int idx, int num) // error: 2 parameters
{
    a[idx] += num;
}
```

One way to solve this would be to use a member `currentIndex` and a setter function. E.g:

```
void setCurrentIndex(int idx)
{
   currentIndex = idx;
}

void operator+(int el)
{
    array12[currentIndex] += el;
}

//usage:
A a;
a.setCurrentIndex(0);
a + 1;
```

As a side note, if you have `operator[]` defined, you can directly do addition:

```
A a;
a[0] += 10;
```

This will need some extra code to make it work if the underlying type is complex.

Comment: It's really not recommended to use `operator+` to update the value. It makes the code less expressive and the bugs are on their way...

Comment: yeah I agree, best not to overload it like this.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly -  pay attention for some misinformation in your question**

- `A[index] + value` - `A` Is the name of the class, not the object of the class.
- `operator+` This operator should **not** update the value, but to return the expected copy result. You probably meant for `operator+=`.

#### For your question

The `operator+=` overloading should be implemented in the type that your array contains. For example, if `array12` contains `int` this code will work as you expected:

```
int main() {
    A a;
    /* ... Some a initialization ... */
    a[3] += 2;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Suppose your `array12` contains a more complex type, for example a custom class named `B`- Then you should overload `operator+=` inside `B`.